# How to determine .NET assembly(component) location?

Tags: .net, dll

My application is using `System.ServiceModel` class reference. On target machine, where my application works and where there is no Visual Studio(or any other development environment) there are lots of System.servicemodel.dll files. I would like to determine which .dll exactly my application is using. Is there any way to figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a type that is defined in the assembly, use that type to get the `Assembly` object, then use the `Location` property to get the path if it was loaded from the hard drive.

```
var path = typeof(System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase).Assembly.Location;
//returns "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" for my machine.
```

Note, if you are using some other assembly and that assembly was loaded using `Assembly.Load(Byte[])` or other similar "pathless" ways to load an assembly then the location property will return a empty string. In that situation you can use `Assembly.CodeBase` to get the location of the caller who loaded the assembly.